# time.Tick stop working when terminal lose focus

Tags: go

This is outputting automateTick log when terminal not lose focus.
I have built automation script using ticker and it stops working when I am doing something else while running this script.
Also it is resumed when I set focus on terminal.

```
var tick <-chan time.Time
    tick = time.Tick(3 * time.Second)

for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            log.Println("<-tick")
        }
    }
```

Any comments on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your terminal is either pausing the process, or just not updating the output.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Is there anyway for terminal to not do that in code? I think golang can enable background tasks (automation tasks I mean)

Comment: I don't know what it would mean to "enable background tasks". It sounds like an energy-savings setting on your system or something. The Go process doesn't have any control over what the OS does to it (e.g. you can't handle a SIGSTOP)

Comment: I see no problem when running your code here on linux. What OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using macOS and this is only relevant part of code - there are other timers as well - 3 timers - not sure if that's affecting

Comment: I had the same issue. After 3 ticks the silence came. In my case the problem was, every tick I send some data to the stream. But no one consumed that stream. At first I thought it's the ticker, but it wasn't.